# Function in mysql

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures

I am have created function in mysql.

This is code of my function

```
 DROP FUNCTION `star`//

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `star`(
num INT

) RETURNS int(11)
DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN

                IF(num>=0 && num<20)
                THEN
                RETURN 1;
                ELSEIF(num>=20 && num<40)
                THEN
                RETURN 2;
                ELSEIF(num>=40 && num<60)
                THEN
                RETURN 3;
                ELSEIF(num>=60 && num<80)
                THEN
                RETURN 4;
                ELSEIF(num>=80 && num<=100)
                THEN
                RETURN 5;
                END IF;
    END
```

I have forgotten how did i made this function in my database. Now i want to create same function into another database.

For this i just copy above code and paste that in sql. and press Go. But it creates error.
Please tell me what mistake i have done.

Comment: What's the error output?

Comment: MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `star`(
    num int
    
    )' at line 1

Comment: When i remove my first line of code then i creates problem in if condition. I dont know whats happening here. Even i created same procedure in one database then why this is creating problem into another database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [`DELIMITER //` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-programs-defining.html) at the top...